# flash as3 - prevent object from being used as dropTarget

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop, droptarget

Is there a way to prevent a flash movieclip (or its children) from being used as a dropTarget? I have objects on the stage which are getting in the way of my determining the underlying stage object where a draggable item is being dropped.

Comment: What do you mean by "objects on the stage which are getting in the way of my determining the underlying stage object"? You have got some objects where you don't wont your other draggable objects to be dropped to. Instead you want the draggable objects to be dropped to the object underneath? Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent a flash movieclip (or its children) from being used as a dropTarget.

You could control it from the other end:

```
function onMouseUp( e:MouseEvent ):void 
{
   var obj = evt.target;
   var target = obj.dropTarget;

   if( target != nonDropAreaMovieClip )
   {
        obj.stopDrag();
   }
}
```

or if you want the obj to be actually dropped to the backgroundMovieClip, which is behind the nonDropAreaMovieClip, you could calculate the global/local coorinates and just do:

```
function onMouseUp( e:MouseEvent ):void 
{
   var obj = evt.target;
   var target = obj.dropTarget;

   if( target != nonDropAreaMovieClip )
   {
        obj.stopDrag();
        obj.x = //calculated x
        obj.y = //calculated y
        backgroundMovieClip.addChild( obj );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around a similar issue by creating movieclips that are transparent and placing them over the drop regions,  or by creating a layer with a transparent object as the topmost layer to prevent the children (in the movieclip) from becoming the dropTarget.